# Disable all gcc warnings

Tags: gcc, g++, warnings

I'm working on a project that will read compiler error messages of a particular variety and do useful things with them. The sample codebase I'm testing this on (a random open-source application), and hence rebuilding frequently, contains a few bits that generate warnings, which are of no interest to me.

How do I disable all warnings from GCC, so I can just see error messages if there are any?

Comment: But please note; you would be better refactoring your code to eliminate the warnings rather than turning them off!

Comment: @Mitch: I believe I've clarified the question to make it clear that I'm neither responsible for nor interested in these warning messages. They really don't matter for these purposes.

Answer (score 392, accepted):

`-w` is the GCC-wide option to disable warning messages.