# cgo how to suppress warnings

Tags: go, cgo

I have a cgo application that uses a C library. During the build process, the compiler shows some warnigns:

```
In file included from ./libsolv-sys/src/qsort_r.c:40:0,
                 from ./libsolv-sys/src/util.c:181,
                 from ./libsolv.go:16:
/usr/include/sys/cdefs.h:1:2: warning: #warning usage of non-standard #include <sys/cdefs.h> is deprecated [-Wcpp]
 #warning usage of non-standard #include <sys/cdefs.h> is deprecated
  ^~~~~~~
```

This library is not maintained by myself and I am not able to fix this warning directly. I am sick of the warning though.

**Question:** How do I suppress warnings in CGO?

**Used CGO Flags:** 
`CFLAGS: -I./libsolv-sys/src -D LIBSOLV_INTERNAL`
`LDFLAGS: ${SRCDIR}/libsolv-sys.a`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

CGO relies on an external compiler toolchain to compile your C code.
On my Linux machine for example, it will default to GCC to compile C code.

For gcc the flag you are looking for is `-w`, so your flags would be:

`-I./libsolv-sys/src -D LIBSOLV_INTERNAL -w`

reference: [Disable all gcc warnings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452671/disable-all-gcc-warnings)

You may need another flag if you are using another toolchain.