# Go-sfml `` is deprecated

Tags: go, gcc, sfml

I set up `sfml` and `csfml` in my environment and then tried installing `go-sfml`, which started returning tons of deprecation warnings. I think I have the right `sfml` versions, so I don't know what is wrong or how to fix it.

I used `winbuilds` to set up `gcc`.

What I did:

`go get -u  gopkg.in/teh-cmc/go-sfml.v24/...`

Returns multiple warnings like:

```
Graphics_wrap.c:6614:3: warning: 'sfShader_setCurrentTextureParameter' is deprecated (declared at c:\users\****\documents\winbuilds\x86_64-w64-mingw32\include\sfml\graphics\shader.h:646) [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
   sfShader_setCurrentTextureParameter(arg1,(char const *)arg2);
```

It also fails to install/build (at least I think that is what it is saying):

````
C:\Program Files\Go\pkg\tool\windows_amd64\link.exe: running gcc failed: exit status 1
c:/users/****/documents/winbuilds/bin/../lib64/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.8.3/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: unrecognized option '--high-entropy-va'
c:/users/****/documents/winbuilds/bin/../lib64/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.8.3/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: use the --help option for usage information
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status```
````

Comment: Did `go-sfml` successfully install? Deprecation warnings don't necessarily result in build errors (note they are *warnings* and not *errors*). You should be able to disable warnings with the `-w` flag ([source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1452674/6069012)).

Comment: what is the sfml version in your local setup. is it above 2.4.0 ?

Comment: I realized I was using csfml 2.5.1 when you told me that, so I thought that was what was wrong and changed the version. Turns out, it still showed the same stuff when I changed the files.

Answer (score 1):

> so I thought that was what was wrong and changed the version.

But this was deprecated in [commit 16ea259](https://github.com/SFML/CSFML/commit/16ea259e04a1a946f0a7655ce5c2acc3d04c430f#diff-eda6e32a6d1dd56b4ce07bd5274278f421b2d045ab21c931c4992fa171a96589R619-R645), Aug. 2016, CSFML 2.4

Since [`teh-cmc/go-sfml`](https://github.com/teh-cmc/go-sfml):

- does require CSFML 2.4,
- does use [`sfShader_setCurrentTextureParameter` in `graphics/Graphics_wrap.c`](https://github.com/teh-cmc/go-sfml/blob/25d755527155cc9e90830e6dc3e8fc78c90e4868/graphics/Graphics_wrap.c#L6603-L6614)

You always will have that warning, unless you patch `go-sfml` itself.